# tmux icon plugins not displaying in status bar

Tags: tmux, tmp

I've installed TPM and am running it last and so on but none of the icons from the icon plugins are displaying correctly, nor do several other things I've added, I don't know what's going on I've tried a few fixes I found on github for issues but none of them work.

I'm not sure what's going on.

This is a link to my [tmux.conf](https://github.com/Thermatix/dotfiles/blob/master/.tmux.conf).

Here's my status bar left and right from the conf:

```
set -g status-left "#[fg=green]#S-: #[fg=brightblue]#{curl icanhazip.com} #[fg=yellow]#{ifconfig en0 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{print \"en0 \" $2}'} #{ifconfig en1 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{print \"en1 \" $2}'} #[fg=red]#{ifconfig tun0 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{print \"vpn \" $2}'} "
set -g status-right "[#{prefix_highlight}|#{online_status}|#{cpu_icon}:#{cpu_percentage}|#{battery_icon}:#{battery_percentage}/#{battery_remain}] %a %h-%d %H:%M:%S#[default]"
```

Here's what my status bar looks like as it stands:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for some reason tpm was thinking it had installed all the plugins I had listed, Obviously it had not, so after manually using the clean_install.sh script I re-ran the install and it worked, so now I have a properly working status bar.